# Bash - variables are not evaluated inside other variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've written a short script which needs to find some text using regex.

I'm incrementing a counter inside a while loop, and this counter is part of another command. Unfortunately this command is always running with the initial counter.

Here a snippet from my code:

```
COUNTER=1
LAST_COMMIT=`git log remotes/origin/devel --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%s | head -${COUNTER}`
JIRA_ID=`echo $LAST_COMMIT | grep -o -P '[A-Z]{2,}-\d+' | xargs`

while [[ ! -z "$JIRA_ID" && $COUNTER -lt "5" ]]; do
        echo "This is the current  counter:  $COUNTER"
        echo "This is the last commit $LAST_COMMIT"
        COUNTER=$[COUNTER+1]
done
echo "this is the counter outside the loop $COUNTER"
```

Comment: You only run the command once. With the initial value of `$COUNTER`. If you need to run it with a different value then you need to run it again. Neither `LAST_COMMIT` nor `JIRA_ID` ever change once set. Also `| xargs` is likely pointless there as it is just `/bin/echo`.

Comment: This might help you; http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion

Comment: Every time you need to get a new `LAST_COMMIT` value you need to run that command. Not just once before the loop. Same thing for every time you want to get a new `JIRA_ID` value (from a new `LAST_COMMIT` value).

Comment: @AlG No. Bad. eval is not even remotely necessary here.

Comment: Also you can tell `git log` how many entries to output directly you don't need `head` for that. And this is going to get you increasingly many lines of output from `git log` each time your `COUNTER` increments and I don't think that's what you want. (Also I think `--pretty=format` is overriding `--pretty=oneline` so you probably don't need both.)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? This probably isn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: So if eval is not a good solution, what should I do ?

Comment: Just run the commands more than once. Once each time through the loop, for example. But better would probably be to answer my question about your ultimate goal since there are probably better solutions than this.

Comment: I want to go over the commits, once I find a Jira ID I'll stop looping , I've made a condition less than 5 in order to demonstrate it

Comment: The while loop also should have the -z condition instead of ! -z

Comment: Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Using a function is the right way to encapsulate code. See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: BTW, think about what would happen if bash expansions were recursive (the way this question's title assumes they should be) -- any time you looked at the value of a variable, any code inside it would be run. That would make it completely impossible to handle untrusted data with bash, making it *completely* unsuited for anything with even the slightest requirement around security.

Answer (score 2):

The best-practices way to encapsulate code (as per [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)) is with a function:

```
get_last_commit() {
  git log remotes/origin/devel --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%s \
    | sed -n "$(( $1 + 1)) p"
}
```

Then:

```
while (( counter < 5 )); do
  last_commit=$(get_last_commit "$counter")
  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a jira_id \
    < <(grep -o -P '[A-Z]{2,}-\d+' <<<"$last_commit") ||:
  [[ $jira_id ]] || break

  echo "This is the current  counter:  $counter"
  echo "This is the last commit $last_commit"
  echo "Found ${#jira_id[@]} jira IDs"
  printf '  %s\n' "${jira_id[@]}"

  (( counter++ ))
done
```

Other notes:

- Use of `read -a`, here, reads the JIRA IDs into an array; you can then ask for the array's length (with `${#jira_id[@]}`), expand a specific entry from the array (with `${jira_id[0]}` to get the first ID, `[1]` for the second, etc); expand them all into an argument list (with `"${jira_id[@]}"`), etc.
- Non-system-defined shell variables should have at least one lower-case character in their names. See the fourth paragraph of the POSIX spec on environment variables at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace. Following this practice prevents you from overwriting system variables by mistake.
- `$(( ... ))` is the POSIX-standard way to enter a math context; `(( ))`, without a leading `$`, is a bash extension.
- While code inside of `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` does not require double quotes to prevent glob expansion or string-splitting, double quotes should be used around expansions in (almost) all other cases.
- `sed '2 p'` gets line 2 more efficiently than `head -2 | tail -n 1`.

---

However, even that is much less efficient than just calling `git log` only one single time and iterating over its results.

```
while IFS= read -r -u 3 last_commit; do
  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a jira_id \
    < <(grep -o -P '[A-Z]{2,}-\d+' <<<"$last_commit") ||:
  [[ $jira_id ]] || continue
  echo "Found ${#jira_id[@]} jira IDs"
  printf '  %s\n' "${jira_id[@]}"
done 3< <(git log remotes/origin/devel --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%s)
```

Comment: The condition in the while should be , unless the Jira ID is empty continue looping, the counter < 5 was just for demonstration, and I didn't want to get an infinite loop. BTW, how do you suggest avoiding the xargs

Comment: `should be ,`? You're missing something. Anyhow, see the `[[ $jira_id ]] || break`, which causes it to stop looping if `jira_id` is ever empty **after** being assigned. Putting that condition in the `while` itself means you never get into the loop to start with, because the variable is empty before the loop's first iteration runs!

Comment: Yes but I can't use the counter < 5 as the loop termination, because I don't know how many commits I'll need to scan

Comment: Then use `while true`.

Comment: That's what I thought, what about avoiding the xargs

Comment: Actually -- with `xargs` defaulting to `echo` when no utility is passed, it's not outright dangerous, just unlikely to be needed. I'll document use of an array instead.

Comment: I've updated this to show use of `read -a` to assemble the IDs into an array.

Comment: Why are you using the internal field separator? What does the [[ $jira_id ]] do ? Why aren't you using the ! -z in order to check if the string is not empty?

Comment: `[ ! -z "$foo" ]` is a damned silly way to write `[ -n "$foo" ]`, which is a more verbose (but also more portable) way to write `[[ $foo ]]`.

Comment: As for IFS, that controls (among other things) how `read` splits records into fields. `grep` divides matches with newlines, so that's what we want for our IFS value.

Comment: So how would you write the opposite using this convention ? (In order to check that the variable doesn't contain any string )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84117/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-user3502786).

Comment: You're a Bash expert!! , I really like your explanations .. I'm a node.js Developer so I'm familiar a little with bash ...

Answer (score 0):

Bash is a procedural language, meaning it contains a series of steps to be carried out in order.

`` LAST_COMMIT=`...` ``is a step that sets the variable `LAST_COMMIT` to the value of the command. You have made this step only execute once, which is why you see the same value over and over.

If you want it to execute again for new values of `$COUNTER`, you can place the statement inside the loop:

```
while
    LAST_COMMIT=`git log remotes/origin/devel --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%s | head -${COUNTER} | tail -n 1`
    JIRA_ID=`echo $LAST_COMMIT | grep -o -P '[A-Z]{2,}-\d+' | xargs`
    [[ ! -z "$JIRA_ID" && $COUNTER -lt "5" ]]
do

    echo "This is the current  counter:  $COUNTER"
    echo "This is the last commit $LAST_COMMIT"
    COUNTER=$[COUNTER+1]
done
echo "this is the counter outside the loop $COUNTER"
```

Since the steps in the loop are executed multiple times, the `` LAST_COMMIT=`...` `` step is also executed multiple times, each time with a new value for `$COUNTER`.

Comment: I think that it's a workaround, because the while shouldn't be running if the first commit contains the JIRA ID, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user3502786 I didn't notice that, but it's still the same concept. You need the statements in the loop. I've updated it.

Comment: So we'd need to make a duplicate code here , which is not good

Comment: @user3502786 Where are you seeing the duplicate code?